# Python and Qt: The main menu of a text editor is not displayed in MacOS 10.15

Tags: python, qt, macos-catalina, mainmenu

I'm developing a text editor with Python and Qt.
The main menu appears in Windows 10.
The main menu is displayed in Ubuntu 20.04.
The main menu is not displayed in MacOS 10.15.

I create the menu as follows:

```
editormenu = self.menuBar ()
```

The following error message appears:

> Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer.
> Unable to create basic Accelerated OpenGL renderer. Core Image is now
> using the software OpenGL renderer. This will be slow.

Two ideas from me that could be:

1. at the integration of the window icon: self.setWindowIcon (QIcon ("PQT-Texteditor.png"))
2. Not enough main memory because MacOS is running in a virtual machine

Question:
Who knows why the main menu is not displayed under MacOs?

Comment: Just to be sure: You _are_ looking in the right place‽  I.e. at the top of the screen and not in the application window‽

Comment: Good idea! I leave MacOS in a virtual machine and it is very slow. If I wait long enough, the editor window will maximize and the editor menu will appear at the top. Problem solved because there was actually no problem. Sorry!